# C++ Dynamic Link Library for both java and C#

Tags: c#, c++, java-native-interface, native

In my application i have few component written in C++, i am successfully able to use these component in JAVA using JNI and in C# using native C++, my question is is it possible to make single dll and use it in both java and C#.

Comment: If you're using a C++/CLI project to _export_ C++ classes to C# then (but I never tried...) why not also C functions required to export C++ classes to Java?

Comment: C++/CLI project can only be used in C# but i am asking for common dll to be used in JAVA and C#

Comment: C++/CLI assembly can export both managed classes (which you can consume in C#/.NET in general) and plain old C functions (which you can consume in Java through JNI). If there isn't any subtle interop issue then it "should" _just_ work (but I still have painful memories about .NET interop with Delphi and C++ Builder native code then I remark "should")

Comment: Let me try and reply back you

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i guess C++/CLI compiled library can start quite heavy .NET runtime in JVM memory ... hard to tell ...

Comment: @JacekCz I agree, it's better to try and see. I have no idea what will be loaded if you do not actually call anything from managed world. Another option would be to try to split into two separate modules in the same assembly (in case modules are loaded on-demand...I don't know) or to embed the C++/CLI interop assembly into a pure managed DLL as a resource (which might be "decompressed" when required). Anyway it's an interesting question (it's not such uncommon to have to provide bridges to Java/Phyton/whatever), I hope OP will post his findings.